# if else only executing else in java

Tags: java, if-statement

so i'm struggling with this problem which seems i cannot understand, im completely new in java and i need help.. so i am making a simple program which will determine if you have passed the subject or not via point grades and it seems it only determines the ELSE STATEMENT.. here's the code.. it will really help me out alot.. thanks in advance

```
    String studID=" ",course=" ", name=" ", dept=" ", subj=" ";
    double exam1=0, exam2=0, exam3=0, exam4=0;
    double avg, pgrade;
    String msg=" ";

studID =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please fill-out the following fields:"
        + "\nStudent ID: ");
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name: ");
dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Department: ");
course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Course: ");
subj = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Subject: ");
exam1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Examination: "));
exam2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second Examination: "));
exam3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Third Examination: "));
exam4 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Final Examination: "));
avg = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3 + exam4)/4;
pgrade =(100 - avg + 10) / 10;

if (avg==100)
{
    msg = "passed - Excellent!";
}else if (avg>100 && avg<89)
{
    msg = "Passed - Very Good!";
}else if (avg>90 && avg<84)
{
    msg = "Passed - Average";
}else if (avg>85 && avg<79)
{
    msg = "Passed - Good";
}else if (avg>80 && avg<74)
{
    msg = "Passed - Satisfactory";
}else if (avg>75 && avg<49)
{
    msg = "Failed";
}else if (avg>50 && avg<0.00)
{   
    msg = "Dropped";
}else if (avg==0.00 && avg<0.00)
{
    msg = "No such Grade";
}else
{
    msg = "Out of Range or Invalid.";
}


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea (
        "|======Student Details=======|"
    + "\n|StudentID:\t" + studID +"\t |"
    + "\n|Name:\t" + name + "\t |"
    + "\n|Department:\t" +dept+ "\t |"
    + "\n|Course:\t"+course+"\t |"
    + "\n|Subject:\t"+subj + "\t |"
    + "\n|=======Grade Details======= |"
    + "\n|First     Second     Third     Fourth  |"
    + "\n|"+exam1+"     "+exam2+"     "+exam3+"     "+exam4+"\t     |"
    + "\n|Average:\t" +avg + "\t|"
    + "\n|Point Grade\t:" +pgrade+"\t|"
    + "\n|Remarks:"+msg+"\t|"
    + "\n|=============================|"));





}
```

}

Comment: Forget Java for a minute: which numbers are greater than 100 *and* less than 89?

Comment: `avg>100 && avg<89` A number cannot be ABOVE 100 and BELOW 89 at the same time. The same applies for all your other `else if` conditions

Comment: @Berger more likely `<=` and `>=` instead of `>` and `<`, respectively.

Comment: Interchange 1st number with the second (ex: avg>89 && avg<100)

Comment: @AndyTurner Probably not `<=` because with `100` for example, there was a separate `if`.

Comment: Why the insane formatting? _Why_? Just use an IDE. It handles that, and many other useful things, for you.

Comment: @AndyTurner : oh yes you're right, I'm removing my comment.

Comment: Welcome to Java Programming! Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger to inspect code like this that isn't performing the way you'd like it to and to see exactly - step by step - what the program is doing

Answer (score 3):

The condition is wrong because to include a variable in a range you have to set

```
else if(avg>89 && avg<100)
```

Comment: Honestly, checking the upper range `&& avg < 100` is entirely unnecessary, because being above 100 shouldn't happen. Plus, since it's a chain of `if else` and it runs top to bottom, it would take the first condition that is true, and skip the rest.

Comment: I know but to be more simplier I choose to write it

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons were wrong to begin with so try something along the lines of what I have corrected, its not the best available, so you can improve it.

```
  String studID=" ",course=" ", name=" ", dept=" ", subj=" ";
    double exam1=0, exam2=0, exam3=0, exam4=0;
    double avg, pgrade;
    String msg=" ";

studID =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please fill-out the following fields:"
        + "\nStudent ID: ");
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name: ");
dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Department: ");
course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Course: ");
subj = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Subject: ");
exam1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Examination: "));
exam2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second Examination: "));
exam3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Third Examination: "));
exam4 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Final Examination: "));
avg = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3 + exam4)/4;
pgrade =(100 - avg + 10) / 10;

if (avg==100)
{
    msg = "passed - Excellent!";
}else if (avg<100 && avg>89)
{
    msg = "Passed - Very Good!";
}else if (avg<90 && avg>84)
{
    msg = "Passed - Average";
}else if (avg<85 && avg>79)
{
    msg = "Passed - Good";
}else if (avg<80 && avg>74)
{
    msg = "Passed - Satisfactory";
}else if (avg<75 && avg>49)
{
    msg = "Failed";
}else if (avg<50 && avg>0.00)
{   
    msg = "Dropped";
}else if (avg==0.00)//no one gets below zero in  a fair system
{
    msg = "No such Grade";
}else
{
    msg = "Out of Range or Invalid.";
}


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea (
        "|======Student Details=======|"
    + "\n|StudentID:\t" + studID +"\t |"
    + "\n|Name:\t" + name + "\t |"
    + "\n|Department:\t" +dept+ "\t |"
    + "\n|Course:\t"+course+"\t |"
    + "\n|Subject:\t"+subj + "\t |"
    + "\n|=======Grade Details======= |"
    + "\n|First     Second     Third     Fourth  |"
    + "\n|"+exam1+"     "+exam2+"     "+exam3+"     "+exam4+"\t     |"
    + "\n|Average:\t" +avg + "\t|"
    + "\n|Point Grade\t:" +pgrade+"\t|"
    + "\n|Remarks:"+msg+"\t|"
    + "\n|=============================|"));





}}
```

Comment: really helped me out a lot, thanks! im still having trouble with operators tbh .

Comment: Just assume you are doing some basic level mathematics. Programming computers is all about making the right calculation in the right place at the right time. Its nothing abstract, its a 'virtual implementation' of a physical solution. LOL